# What happen to items with unique permission, if we should to have their list inherit its permission from the site rather than having unique permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, inheritance, break-inheritance

I am reading this official link inside Microsoft docs @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-is-permissions-inheritance .. and the link mentioned the following sentence:-

> When a user shares or stops sharing an item that contains other items
> with broken inheritance, a one-time push down of that permission
> addition or removal is sent to all child items, even those with broken
> inheritance

but based on my test if I have a list which has unique permissions and this list contain items with unique permissions also >> then if I chose that the list should inherit the permissions from its site rather than having unique permission >> then this action will not push down to the items.. where the items will still have unique permissions.. so is the above sentence wrong? or i am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign **unique permissions** to the list, the **items** in the list will also **automatically inherit the unique permissions of the list**.

[image]

[image]

If the **list inherits the permissions** from site collection and does not have unique permissions. **Unless you grant unique permissions to the specific item, items will automatically inherit the permissions of the site collection.**

[image]

[image]

=========================== **Updated Answer** =================================

This **push down action** is only for **permissions**, and does not mean that anything I do on the list will also be transferred to the item.

For example, restoring the inheritance operation of the list (**Delete unique permissions**) does not turn the item from the "**unique permissions**" state to the "**inherited**" state

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, but you did not answer my question...

Comment: Hi, john Gu. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: can you please explain what do u mean by "This push down action is only for permissions, "?

Comment: Hi, john Gu. For example, when you delete a user permission at the site level, the user permission is also automatically deleted at the list level and item level.